# How can I find which intrinsic sets my cpu supports with command-line tools?

Tags: windows, command-line, x86, cpu, avx

Is it possible to know if my CPU suports AVX, MMX, SSE, and etc. from Windows cmd, or powershell? Or just via Windows control panel or anything?

I know that I can use tools like CPU-Z(https://cpu-z.en.softonic.com/) to figure things out, but I would like to know how to do it without installing softwares.

Comment: If you have gcc installed, run `gcc -march=native` and parse the output.  `gcc -v -xc /dev/null -O3 -march=native -o- -E 2>&1 | grep -o -- '-m[-a-z0-9=]*'` will print stuff like `-msse` and `-mavx`, and `-mno-avx512f` for features you don't have.  See [How do I identify which CPU a MacBook uses?](//apple.stackexchange.com/a/238864) for more explanation.  Obviously you need a `grep` installed too.  If you don't have a Unix-style shell + compiler installed on your Windows machine, then IDK.  (Otherwise I'd post this as an answer)

Comment: @PeterCordes That was very helpful. Thank you.